# chrome.runtime.sendmessage extension id not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a very weird problem on Chrome.

The [document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage) says the first argument should be a Chrome extension ID.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('bgmpeololjflcbghnmfkfldminickkog', { text: "hogee." })
```

Something like the above, right?

When I run

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('bgmpeololjflcbghnmfkfldminickkog', { text: "hogee." })
```

or

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ text: "hogee." })
```

on the extension context, let's say `my-extension` context on the console, it works.

But when I run the above two lines on the `top` context (the page context), the first line one doesn't work, and the second line one doesn't work w/ an error.

Ofc I'm making sure the extension id is correct. On the `my-extenson` context, `chrome.runtime.id` then I get the id `bgmpeololjflcbghnmfkfldminickkog`.

I'm confused, no idea what's wrong (or not wrong, is it a bug?) here.

Comment: You need to use [external messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external-webpage), it needs a different listener: onMessageExternal.

Comment: I replaced `onMessage` with `onMessageExternal`, added `"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ],
    "ids": [
      "*"
    ]
  },`, but it doesn't work. I put a breakpoint on the first line of `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener` callback function, and tried to run `chrome.runtime.sendMessage('bgmpeololjflcbghnmfkfldminickkog', { text: "hogee." })` on the `top` (the web page) context, it doesn't hit. No error message. What am I missing here? @wOxxOm

Comment: I can't really hepl without see the new [MCVE](/help/mcve). Note that onMessageExternal must be in the background script.